# How to get the lastcell plus one of a excell file

Tags: c#, excel, range, worksheet

I have a excell file with 10 sheets with headers in row 1.
I'm using this bit of code to get a range of those headers. That part works fine.

```
 string  lastColumn      = worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Address[Type.Missing].Substring(1, 1);
            Range   amountRange     = worksheet.Range["A1", string.Format("{0}1", lastColumn)];
```

The thing is I' getting a new sheet with the same headers, but I have to add one dinamically. I have to read it from a DB.

So if I change the code to this, I get just the last column. No sweat.

```
string  lastColumn      = worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Address[Type.Missing].Substring(1, 1);
                    Range   amountRange     = worksheet.Range[string.Format("{0}1", lastColumn)];
```

But what I want is to get the last column plus one and I'm struggling with it.
My first thought was lastColumn  + 1, but it does not work.
Any ideas.
Rui Martins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.

After getting the column name of the last column, I converted it to a number, added 1 and then converted back into a column name.

That easy.